# placing a widget in a custom tab

Tags: magento-1.9

[Create product tab that displays custom attribute - Ultimo Theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63105/create-product-tab-that-displays-custom-attribute-ultimo-theme)

I have done this and created a Tab.

I want this tab to display a gallery that I have created with an extension.

`{{block type="gallery/show" id="front-page-gallery"}}`

I am given this display code.

However all that displays is the code, How do I get it to display the gallery. I tried placing it in a block, and that had the same results.